# How to insert a border into a table cell such that it doesn't mess up the table

Tags: html, css, typescript, primeng

I have an ng table where I wish to dynamically apply a border to the cells.

I'm able to do this.  However, it gets the table cells out of alignment, especically if I'm trying to do a thick border...

[image: Ack! The cells are out of alignment!]

I've messed around with the width of the cells and such but what I really want it to do is just keep the cells the exact same size they already are but with a border strictly on the inside of the cells.

Here is my html code.  Not too much to it...

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-year let-columns="columns" let-editing="editing" let- 
   ri="rowIndex">
    <tr [pEditableRow]="year">

        <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngClass]="{'schedule-cell-non-zero'}"></td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

And here is my .scss code.  Again not much to it..

```
.schedule-cell-non-zero {

  $color-border: $--laps-light-green;
  
  &.inset-border {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  }
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  border: 10px solid $color-border;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  font-weight: 300;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  
  
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks much

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) CSS property
`box-sizing: border-box;` on the `schedule-cell-non-zero` class name.

Comment: Thanks much - that's a thousand times better.

Something else I forgot to ask - is there any way to get it to render the right border?

Comment: No problem, if you make a codesandbox, or jsfiddle I could have a look for you.

Comment: Thanks.  Just talking about if there is any way to do it such that the right side isn't missing the border (see above).

Comment: When trying the code you have above on my system I am not able to reproduce the screenshot. A jsfiddle with the minimal code needed to reproduce the table in the screenshot will help in fixing your specific situation.